# BigQuery - retrying failed insert job

Tags: google-bigquery

I am having a question on retrying failed insert jobs in BigQuery. As per BigQuery's documentation in [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery#consistency) link, we can retry as many times as we want with the same job id and only one job will succeed.

> Note that calling jobs.insert() on a given job ID is idempotent; in
>   other words, you can retry as many times as you like on the same job
>   ID, and at most one of those operations will succeed.

But when I retry later on a failed (DONE with errors) job with the same id, it fails with the below error.

```
{
  "code" : 409,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Already Exists: Job bigquery-eval:INSERT-user_sessions-sessions_test-168-06-10-2015",
    "reason" : "duplicate"
  } ],
  "message" : "Already Exists: Job bigquery-eval:INSERT-user_sessions-sessions_test-168-06-10-2015"
}
```

Could you guys please clarify me why this fails and how do we retry this? As per my understanding, this should not fail. Please correct me if my expectation is wrong.

I also would like to know the behavior of BigQuery when there are concurrent insert requests with the same job id. I know this should not happen. But would like to understand. I see lot of these errors when I run lot of concurrent processes doing inserts. But not able to determine the reason from the response.

**EDITED**

This is the response I get when I do a get on that id. Apparently, it has completed with errors because of a newline char at the end.

```
{
  "id": "bigquery-eval:INSERT-user_sessions-sessions_test-168-06-10-2015",
  "status": {
    "state": "DONE",
    "errorResult": {
      "reason": "invalid",
      "message": "Too many errors encountered. Limit is: 0."
    },
    "errors": [
      {
        "reason": "invalid",
        "location": "File: 0 / Offset:0 / Line:1 / Column:2411 / Field:",
        "message": "parse error: trailing garbage\n"
      },
      {
        "reason": "invalid",
        "message": "Too many errors encountered. Limit is: 0."
      }
    ]
  },
  "statistics": {
    "creationTime": "1444150359688",
    "startTime": "1444151563664",
    "endTime": "1444151566721",
    "load": {
      "inputFiles": "1",
      "inputFileBytes": "19091357",
      "outputRows": "0",
      "outputBytes": "0"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: hmmm I found this doc https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing_jobs_datasets_projects that explains you need to do a job.get, change the ID, jobID, status, and statistics field and throw it again to run it again.

Comment: Also, Done with errors != failed... does it have an errorState?

Comment: hmmm. I had missed this. But I am wondering how this helps in making idempotent inserts. And the link that I posted suggests to retry with the same job id. Which one is correct? Yes. It does have errorResult. The error was the file had newline char at the end of the file. The number of allowed errors in my case is 0. So, this file shouldn't be loaded (as it is atomic). Hence the job is completed(DONE) with errors.

Comment: that is a very good question. Right now my theory is that if it's successful, it won't let you run it again, but if it failed it can try again. As you said it was done but with errors... it means it had errors, not that it failed. Does it have an errorState? You can have problematic rows (that'll end up being errors on your response) but still have a successful job

Comment: I have edited my original post to include the old job details. Please check.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me in BigQuery. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Might be a bug, might not be a bug, it depends on which doc you look at. The proper thing here might be to send a defect report to the BigQuery team's Issue Tracker, available here :https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list. It's either a doc correction that's needed, or you're right and it's an issue.

Comment: Thanks. Have opened this bug and here is the link. https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=343